# add a png image to an existing pdf in django using reportlab

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am trying to add a .png file in an existing pdf. I got an example,i edited the position of .png in pdf to place it in left-bottom corner and when i run it, it is creating new pdf. I tried to go through reportlab's documentation to get any hits but failed. What should i do to achieve the desired result? I want to achieve it though any 3rd party python package or related to python code not using photoshp or adobe acrobat.

```
def PrintImage(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response,rightMargin=600,
            leftMargin=0,
            topMargin=150,
            bottomMargin=18)
    doc.pagesize = landscape(A4)
    elements = []
    I = Image('static/images/account.png')
    I.drawHeight =  1.0*inch
    I.drawWidth = 1.0*inch
    elements.append(I)
    doc.build(elements)
    return response
```

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with Django does it?

Comment: @thebjorn well i am implementing this in django,so my question is wrong?well have edited it.

Comment: I meant that you can remove all the django code and still see the same problem, correct? If so you should remove the django code (and the django tag) since that is only adding complexity and not any understanding of the problem you're seeing. (This is the M in MCVE). You should also include the import statements (the C in MCVE).